# For what value of $n$ is $\frac {a^n}{b^n} < \epsilon$ for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ with $a,b \in \Bbb R$ and $a<b$.

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $a,b \in \Bbb R$ satisfy $a<b$, Then for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ for which value of $n \in \Bbb N$ does $\frac {a^n}{b^n} < \epsilon$.

Taking the logarithm in base $\epsilon$ gives me $ nlog_{\epsilon} \frac{a}{b} < 1$. But this seems to not be useful because I want to show that $n$ is larger than some expression. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick with logarithms base $e = 2.718281828459..$

As $0 <a < b,$
$$  \frac{a}{b} < 1 $$
so
$$ \log \frac{a}{b} < 0 $$

Nothing interesting is going on unless $\epsilon < 1,$ so that
$$ \log \epsilon < 0.  $$
$$ n \log \frac{a}{b} < \log \epsilon, $$ dividing both sides by the negative $\log \frac{a}{b},$ switches the inequality sign and gives
$$ n > \frac{\log \epsilon}{\log \frac{a}{b}} $$

Just for comparison, if
$$  -10 x < -3,  $$ then
$$  10 x > 3  $$ and
$$ x > \frac{3}{10} $$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {a^n}{b^n} < \epsilon$

If $0 < a < b$

Then $\frac ab >0$ and $n < \log_{\frac ab}\epsilon < 0$ (as $0< a/b < 1$). So $n > -\log_{\frac ab}\epsilon$.

If $a < 0< b$

Then $\frac ab < 0$ and we don't know if $|\frac ab| <,>,= 1$

then $\frac {a^n}{b^n} < 0$ if $n$ is odd, and $\frac {a^n}{b^n} > 0$ if $n$ is even. If $|\frac ab| < 1$,  select $n = 2m >  -\log_{|\frac ab|}\epsilon > 0$.  If $|\frac ab| >1$ select $n = 2m < \log_{|\frac ab|}\epsilon$. And if $|\frac ab| = 1$ i.e.$ a= -b$ and $0 < \epsilon < 1$ we can only have this occur if $n$ is odd and $\frac {a^n}{b^n} = -1 < 0 < \epsilon$.

If $a < b < 0$ then $n < \log_{\frac ab}\epsilon$. As $a/b > 1$, this will only hold for *small* values of $n$ so this will not help you.